# How to format a date with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong here. I'm wanting to format the `date_published` field in my query and I'm getting a `t_string syntax error` in my IDE.

```
$this->db->select('site_news_articles.article_title, site_news_articles.is_sticky,' date_format('site_news_articles.date_published, 'f jS, Y')');
```

UPDATE:

```
function getNewsTitles($category_id) {
    $this->db->select('site_news_articles.article_title, site_news_articles.is_sticky');
    $this->db->select("DATE_FORMAT(site_news_articles.date_published, '%M %e, %Y') as formatted_date", TRUE);
    $this->db->from('site_news_articles');
    $this->db->where('site_news_articles.news_category_id', $category_id); 
    $this->db->where('site_news_articles.is_approved', 'Yes');
    $this->db->where('site_news_articles.status_id', 1);
    $this->db->order_by('site_news_articles.date_published', 'desc');  
    $this->db->limit(10);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array(); 
}
```

Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM (`site_news_articles`) WHERE `site_news_articles`.`news_category_id` = 2 A' at line 2

SELECT `site_news_articles`.`article_title`, `site_news_articles`.`is_sticky`, DATE_FORMAT(site_news_articles.date_published, `'%M` %e, `%Y')` as formatted_date FROM (`site_news_articles`) WHERE `site_news_articles`.`news_category_id` = 2 AND `site_news_articles`.`is_approved` = 'Yes' AND `site_news_articles`.`status_id` = 1 ORDER BY `site_news_articles`.`date_published` desc LIMIT 10

Filename: /home/xtremer/public_html/models/sitemodel.php

Line Number: 140

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you have a syntax error.

```
$this->db->select("site_news_articles.article_title, site_news_articles.is_sticky, DATE_FORMAT(site_news_articles.date_published, '%M %D, %Y')", FALSE);
```

Whenever you're building a query in CI, you should used double quotes to surround it, so you can use the single quotes in your query without having to escape them.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed the code to use the correct parameters for the MySQL DATE_FORMAT() function.

Comment: CI is probably ruining the code by trying to escape field names. I updated the code to pass in the second parameter as FALSE to the db->select() function

Comment: I would improve this by adding an AS clause at the end otherwise addressing that value in you main code is ugly.$this->db->select("site_news_articles.article_title, site_news_articles.is_sticky, DATE_FORMAT(site_news_articles.date_published, '%M %D, %Y') AS human_date", FALSE);

Comment: why are we using false/

Answer (score 6):

You're trying to execute PHP **within** a mysql query. You need to be using the MySQL `DATE_FORMAT` function.  Take a look here:

http://davidwalsh.name/format-date-mysql-date_format

```
$this->db->select('site_news_articles.article_title, site_news_articles.is_sticky');
$this->db->select("DATE_FORMAT(site_news_articles.date_published, '%M %e, %Y') as formatted_date", FALSE);
```

the `$this->db->select()` method is used to 'generate' a sql query - so trying to use the CI `date_format` function there, will not generate the correct sql query that will be executed on your database.

You can either return the raw date with your query and then format the date with CI, or you need to use the MySQL `DATE_FORMAT` function to return the formatted date with mysql.

Comment: Oops, I passed true instead of false in the select method. Sorry about that. Updated my post.

Answer (score 4):

try to use mdate:

```
echo mdate('%M %d, %Y at exactly %h:&i %a',strtotime(date));
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you forgot a single quote

```
$this->db->select("site_news_articles.article_title, site_news_articles.is_sticky, date_format(site_news_articles.date_published, 'f jS, Y')");
```

Comment: Only problem is its saying now that... Message: date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTime, string given   which is strange because in my db the field is a datetime datatype field

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be to use php's date format

```
date(string format [, int timestamp])
```

So...

```
date('Y-m-d h:i:s', 'site_news_articles.date_published')
```

Comment: This wouldn't work in a query - only in PHP. He's building a query, not formatting the output.