# Getting syntax error when using mysql DATE_FORMAT

Tags: php, mysql

I am using mysql `DATE_FORMAT` for a specific datetime in database. Mysql Query is:

```
$this->db->select('remarks_date, DATE('remarks_date') AS rem_dateonly, DATE_FORMAT('remarks_date', '%y-%m-%d %h:%i') AS day_hour_mins, DATE_FORMAT('remarks_date', '%y-%m-%d %h') AS day_hour, tbl_complain_detail.complain_summary, tbl_complain_detail.id, tbl_complain_detail.complain_no, tbl_complain_detail.created_by, escalation_status, tbl_admin_user.first_name, tbl_admin_user.middle_name, tbl_admin_user.last_name');
$this->db->where('tbl_complain_remarks.status', 'Time Extension');
$this->db->where('tbl_complain_detail.status !=', 'Completed');
$this->db->where('tbl_complain_detail.time_extension_status', '1');
$this->db->join('tbl_complain_remarks', 'tbl_complain_remarks.complain_id = tbl_complain_detail.id');
$this->db->join('tbl_admin_user', 'tbl_admin_user.id = tbl_complain_detail.user_id');
$result2 = $this->db->get('tbl_complain_detail')->result();
```

Here I am getting error as

`PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in select line`

and also it's not taking `%`. Why?

Am I doing something wrong? Any help/suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Try to echo the query so that you can see the constructed query.

Comment: echo your query and show the result

Comment: Add DATE(remarks_date) without quotes if use quotes means it consider as a string

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is with the alias in the table. For using alias in the table use `` symbol. Try this one.

```
SELECT remarks_date AS rem_date_only, DATE_FORMAT(remarks_date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i") AS `day_hour_mins`, DATE_FORMAT(remarks_date, "%Y-%m-%d %H") AS `day_hour`, tbl_complain_detail.complain_summary, tbl_complain_detail.id, tbl_complain_detail.complain_no, tbl_complain_detail.created_by, escalation_status, tbl_admin_user.first_name, tbl_admin_user.middle_name, tbl_admin_user.last_name
FROM (`tbl_complain_detail`)
JOIN `tbl_complain_remarks` ON `tbl_complain_remarks`.`complain_id` = `tbl_complain_detail`.`id`
JOIN `tbl_admin_user` ON `tbl_admin_user`.`id` = `tbl_complain_detail`.`user_id`
WHERE `tbl_complain_remarks`.`status` =  'Time Extension'
AND `tbl_complain_detail`.`status` != 'Completed'
AND `tbl_complain_detail`.`time_extension_status` =  '1'
```

Answer (score 2):

You use single quote with simple string. Use double quote for complex string.

```
$this->db->select("remarks_date, DATE(remarks_date) AS rem_dateonly, DATE_FORMAT(remarks_date, '%y-%m-%d %h:%i') AS day_hour_mins, DATE_FORMAT(remarks_date, '%y-%m-%d %h') AS day_hour, tbl_complain_detail.complain_summary, tbl_complain_detail.id, tbl_complain_detail.complain_no, tbl_complain_detail.created_by, escalation_status, tbl_admin_user.first_name, tbl_admin_user.middle_name, tbl_admin_user.last_name", false);
```

Comment: Asuraya and Manibharathi .. I am getting error as 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':%i) AS day_hour_mins

Comment: OK. i change it. check it now.

Comment: Still I am getting error as
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '%'

Comment: I add false value as params according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8125274/how-to-format-a-date-with-codeigniter. check it now

Answer (score 0):

Mysql doesn't support `'` single quotes when specify column in select query so use this

```
DATE(`remarks_date`)
```

OR

```
DATE(remarks_date)
```

Instead of

`DATE('remarks_date')`

```
$this->db->select('remarks_date, DATE(`remarks_date`) AS rem_dateonly, DATE_FORMAT(`remarks_date`, "%y-%m-%d %h:%i") AS day_hour_mins, DATE_FORMAT(`remarks_date`, "%y-%m-%d %h") AS day_hour, tbl_complain_detail.complain_summary, tbl_complain_detail.id, tbl_complain_detail.complain_no, tbl_complain_detail.created_by, escalation_status, tbl_admin_user.first_name, tbl_admin_user.middle_name, tbl_admin_user.last_name');
```

Comment: @sammy watch my updated answer. use `DATE_FORMAT(remarks_date, "%y-%m-%d %h:%i")` instead of `DATE_FORMAT(remarks_date, %y-%m-%d %h:%i)`